# Failed to configure discovery strategies in com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.0.2 in AWS ECS/EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I got "Failed to configure discovery strategies" in AWS ECS/EC2
error for compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.0.2'

but working fine for compile 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:3.12.5'

Bellow is the error. Can anybody help me to understand the reason?

```
2021-09-23 22:17:03 INFO  com.hazelcast.system.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Hazelcast 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) starting at [10.0.11.27]:5701
2021-09-23 22:17:03 INFO  com.hazelcast.system.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2021-09-23 22:17:04 INFO  com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Backpressure is disabled
2021-09-23 22:17:04 INFO  com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy.java Line 49: Using AWS discovery plugin with configuration: AwsConfig{accessKey='***', secretKey='***', iamRole='null', region='eu-west-2', hostHeader='null', securityGroupName='uat-servers', tagKey='Name', tagValue='exalt-priceuat', hzPort=5701-5701, cluster='null', family='null', serviceName='null', connectionTimeoutSeconds=120, connectionRetries=3, readTimeoutSeconds=10}
2021-09-23 22:17:19 INFO  com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Shutting down connection manager...
2021-09-23 22:17:19 INFO  com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Shutting down node engine...
2021-09-23 22:17:19 INFO  com.hazelcast.instance.impl.NodeExtension.java Line 49: [10.0.11.27]:5701 [dev] [4.0.2] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2021-09-23 22:17:19 WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.java Line 557: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springAsyncConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationParameterService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationParameterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'applicationParameterRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationParameterRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#526e8108' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#526e8108': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/HazelcastCacheConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hazelcast/HazelcastServerConfiguration$HazelcastServerConfigFileConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to configure discovery strategies
```

Comment: Have you checked the hazelcast changelog between versions 3.12.5 and 4.0.2? Since that is a major version bump they are not expected to be interchangeable. https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/migration-guides#removal-of-hazelcast-client-module